# Is there a free or opensource barcode reader

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am working on python script. And need to scan some PDF417 baracodes. Is there any free or opensource library for this.
I found dynamsoft barcode reader which is very good at this but its need a paid version to use.

Comment: This may be helpful. [brdamico/PDF417BarcodeReader](https://github.com/brdamico/PDF417BarcodeReader)

Answer (score 5):

You can consider using Zxing. Zxing is a free open source library that can scan PDF417 barcodes, you can get the source code from the link below:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Hope this can help you.